# Ruby: Yielding from an inner block does not work

Tags: ruby, lambda, yield, proc

I am working on a Ruby project that outputs text where I want to allow other code to change part of the wrapper. Below is a simplified example:

- Outer wrappers of the output are generated by this project
- Inner wrapper is generated by user-specified code
- Inside this inner wrapper, calling `yield` will make the project generate the inner contents.

However, I get a very strange error when attempting to run the following code:

```
def wrapper(&block)
  puts "begin outer wrapper"
  block.call do
    puts "inner content"
  end
  puts "end outer wrapper"
end

wrapper do
  puts "begin inner wrapper"
  yield
  puts "end inner wrapper"
end
```

I would expect the following output:

```
begin outer wrapper
begin inner wrapper
inner content
end inner wrapper
end outer wrapper
```

This does not happen. Instead, Ruby throws the following error: `LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)`

What is going wrong?

**EDIT:** Based on @JörgWMittag's answer, this is a variant that *does* work:

```
def wrapper(&block)
  puts "begin outer wrapper"
  block.call do
    puts "inner content"
  end
  puts "end outer wrapper"
end

wrapper do |&inner_block|
  puts "begin inner wrapper"
  inner_block.call
  puts "end inner wrapper"
end
```

Basically, `yield` and `Proc#call()` are very different beasts after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is going wrong?

`yield` transfers control to the block that was passed to the method in whose definition the `yield` appears. In your case, the `yield` doesn't appear in a method definition, ergo, there is nowhere to `yield` to.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a while to understand your answer, but now it is clear.

Basically, when I refer to the block as a parameter inside the `wrapper do`, I can then do #call on that without problems. So this code *does* work:

`def wrapper(&block)
  puts "begin outer wrapper"
  block.call do
    puts "inner content"
  end
  puts "end outer wrapper"
end

wrapper do |&passed_block|
  puts "begin inner wrapper"
  passed_block.call
  puts "end inner wrapper"
end`

It seems that, `yield` and `#call` are not as similar as most explanations on the web would make you believe...